# Easy Way To Send HTML Formatted Email in C++

Tags: c++, html, perl, forms

I have an HTML form that currently takes the inputs and sends them out in an email with HTML formatting, so that the email looks basically like the form webpage, but with all of the fields filled in.

```
<form method="post" action="/cgi-bin/perlscript.pl" enctype="x-www-form-encoded" name="Form">
   <input type="text" name="txtMyText" id="txtMyText" />
</form>
```

The post-action script is written in Perl, and I am currently converting it to C++ simply because it is much easier for me to read and maintain that way.  Also, I think it is more flexible for future additions.

In Perl, I was able to use "SendMail" to send the email, and I could do something like this:

```
sub PrintStyles
{
print MAIL <<ENDMAIL
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
        h1.title { color: Red; }
        h3.title { color : Black; background-color: yellow; }
        </style>

<!-- Put any valid HTML here that you want -->
<!-- You can even put variables ($xxxx) into the HTML as well, like this: -->
                <td>$myVariable</td>

ENDMAIL
}
```

What was nice about that, was I could literally copy-and-paste my entire CSS and HTML files (very lengthy) as long as they were in-between the "ENDMAIL" tags, and they would show up perfectly.  I could even put the variables in there without having to do any extra work.

My questions is: **Is there a C++ library that has similar functionality?**  I really don't think I can afford to do something like this:

```
cout << "<html>" << endl;
cout << "<head>" << endl;
cout << "......" << endl;
```

I'd like it to be fairly light-weight.

Thanks.

Comment: C/C++ do not support [`here`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document) documents. It will need to be a quoted string. But the compiler will auto concatenate multiple strings in a source file.

Comment: Don't use `endl`. Just use `'\n'`. It's faster, and just as portable.

Comment: There must be a good templating library in C++ that would generate the email body. You want a nice MIME library for generating the email itself, but the body of the HTML message should be done by a templating engine.

Comment: @Omnifarious: Do you mean faster as in performance? I rather like keeping the "endl" separate for visual reasons, and I can type it faster than \n.

Comment: Yes, better performing. It's flushing all the time, and for outputting a ton of HTML that's totally unnecessary. Someone should come up with a nicely named character constant for everybody to use that doesn't flush all the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you all for the responses.  I have decided to simply call the Perl script from my code, and send the response data as an argument.  I know it's probably not the best solution, but I don't think my C++ options were worth it.

```
// Retrieve the POST data    
char* contentLength = getenv{"CONTENT_LENGTH"};
int contentSize     = atoi(contentLength);
char* contentBuffer = (char*)malloc(contentSize);
fread(contentBuffer, 1, contentSize, stdin);
string data         = contentBuffer;

// Execute "sendmail.pl" script
string perlFile     = "sendmail.pl";
string command      = "perl " + perlFile + " \"" + data + "\"";
system(command.c_str());
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way I know of is to use [SMTPClientSession](http://pocoproject.org/docs/Poco.Net.SMTPClientSession.html) class from [POCO C++](http://pocoproject.org/) Libraries.
Here is a [good example](http://blog.neofig.com/2011/01/30/send-mail-by-poco-cpp-libraries/).

Answer (score 1):

You could define the text as a `const char *` which would ease the pain and suffering of outputting each line via `cout`:

```
const char email_text[] =
"<html>\n"
"<head>\n"
"....";

cout.write(email_text, sizeof(email_text) - 1);
cout.flush();

std::string email_string(email_text);
cout << email_text;
cout.flush();
```

I haven't used the library, but my guess is that you will need to pass it either an `std::string` or a `char *`.

Answer (score 1):

You might consider [mimetic](http://www.codesink.org/mimetic_mime_library.html)

Answer (score 1):

C++ does not support here documents.
You will need to use a string and send it to the stream you want:

```
void PrintStyles(ostream& mailstream)
{

    mailstream <<  
    "<html>\n"
    "    <head>\n"
    "        <style>\n"
    "        h1.title { color: Red; }\n"
    "        h3.title { color : Black; background-color: yellow; }\n"
    "        </style>\n"
    "\n"
    "<!-- Put any valid HTML here that you want -->\n"
    "<!-- You can even put variables (" << xxxx << ") into the HTML as well, like this: -->\n"
    "                <td>" << myVariable << "</td>\n"
    "\n"
    "\n";
}
```

Were you get mail stream from will depend on what email package you are using.

Comment: Thank you for the link.  I was not familiar with the term "here documents."